# How to validate form fields on its default values using serializeArray().?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Have a basic registration form, trying to validate it.

I am using form `serializeArray()` method and loop trough the form and find if the values are null.

**HTML CODE**

```
<form name="reg" id="regform">
    <fieldset>

        <label for="firstname">First Name</label>

            <input type="text" name="firstname" value="First Name"/>

    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>

        <label for="lastname">Last name</label>

        <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Last Name"/>

    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
        <label for="date">Age</label>

        <input type="text" name="age"/>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

**JQUERY Code**

```
var formElements = $("#regform").serializeArray();

$(formElements).each(function(x)
{
    if(formElements[x]["value"] == "")
    {
        $("[name='" + formElements[x]['name'] +"']").addClass('error');
    }
});
```

From the above code i am able to add the class ".error" when the value is null.

Now i want the code to check the text fields values are not the default values like in my case the default values are "First Name" "Last Name"..

So i want to check even for the default values and add error class to respective element and even focus back the cursor on the first null value text field

Thanks in advance

Comment: You may want to look at the HTML5 `placeholder` attribute as an alternative to putting the placeholder values in the `value` attribute. If it needs to work on older versions of IE, you could use a plugin like [this one](https://github.com/andrewrjones/jquery-placeholder-plugin).

Comment: Never mind, I think you just meant "First Name" etc. as examples, and it would actually be the person's name.

Comment: Thanks @MattBrowne for taking time for my question. First my approach was to use `placeholder` but my users are mainly on IE8, about 80%. I dont want to use a plugin as i am already using good amount of plugins for other major modules. so thought of having the validation done without plugin.

Comment: The `placeholder` plugins are very lightweight, and the only practical alternative would be to store all the default values in a Javascript object when the page first loads so you could compare them to see which ones changed. If you're concerned about multiple HTTP requests then you could bundle the minified code of your most common plugins into a single file.

Comment: Also, I like to follow the principle of coding more with the future in mind than the past (i.e. consider future support just as much as backward-compatibility). If you use `placeholder`, in a few years you may be glad you did so.

Comment: Input elements have a `defaultValue` property in DOM, so you can just use `$("#formfieldxy")[0].defaultValue` to read the value that the field originally had specified via the `value` attribute in HTML. (`[0]` to de-reference the jQuery object so that you have a real DOM node reference.)

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest using http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation. You can test for various things, such as blank values, and even extend it to detect default values.

For example:

`$.validator.addMethod("name", function(value) {
    return value != "First Name";
}, 'Please enter your first name.');`

---

Alternatively you can just test against a default value with [jQuery's `data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) function:

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WpQ2n/2/

```
var input = $(".name"),
    defaultval = input.data("default", input.val()); 

// Can't submit forms in jsfid, so i just used a click event. 
// Change to .submit()

$("input[type='submit']").on("click",function(e){
    if(input.val()== input.data("default")){
        input.addClass("error"); 
    }
    else{
    // Yay it validated...
        input.removeClass("error");
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```